# Estimate from above $\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n^\alpha-m^\alpha}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Find an upper bound for
$$\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n^\alpha-m^\alpha}$$
with $\alpha>1$. I do not know where to start but, for example, if $\alpha=1$ the previous sum is linked to Harmonic numbers $H_n$ that have the following upper bound
$$H_n\le\log(n)+\gamma+\frac1{2n}$$
What happens for $\alpha>1$?